# How to convert String to Permission in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package
I need to convert string to permission
E.g: "location" is string, need to convert Permission.location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think there are two solutions:**

1. With the ability to manage names
   Make enum with all Permission's values and static extension method that get as field String and returns Permission

```dart
extension NamedPermission on Permission {
  static Permission fromName(String permissionName) {
    switch (permissionName) {
      case 'location':
        return Permission.location;
      case 'contacts':
        return Permission.contacts;
      // other... 
      default:
        return Permission.unknown;
    }
  }
}

main() {
  print(NamedPermission.fromName('location'));
  //Result: Permission.location
}
```

2. Concise and simple but without the ability to manage names

```dart
extension NamedPermission on Permission {
  static Permission fromName(String permissionName) {
    final matchedPermissions =
        Permission.values.where((e) => e.toString() == permissionName);
    if (matchedPermissions.isNotEmpty) return matchedPermissions.first;
    return Permission.unknown;
  }
}

main() {
  print(NamedPermission.fromName('location'));
  //Result: Permission.location
}
```

Comment: The `toString()`method returns `'Permission.${_names[value]}'`, so you would have to pass "Permission.location" string to your `fromName` function, not "location". I think you better use `Permission.values.firstWhere((e) => e.toString() == 'Permission.$permissionName')` to get the `Permission` object from the name.

Comment: 2nd options very useful to me but need small correction brother. Change e.toString() == permissionName to e.toString() == "Permission.$permissionName"